# JOINS & comparing

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL,  stuck in executing these query together, looking for optimized way of clubbing them together.for two different scenarios of same tables.
I/p data looks like this.

Table A

```
+----+--------+----------+-------+
| ID | Source | Product# | State |
+----+--------+----------+-------+
|  1 | Fin    |    22200 | CA    |
|  2 | Mfg    |   111225 | CA    |
|  3 | Fin    |          | CA    |
|  4 | Fin    |    22223 | CA    |
|  5 | Fin    |          | CA    |
+----+--------+----------+-------+
```

Table B

```
+----+--------+----------+-------+
| ID | Source | Product# | State |
+----+--------+----------+-------+
|  1 | Fin    |    22200 | CA    | 
|  2 | Fin    |   111225 | CA    | 
|  3 | Fin    |    44445 | CA    | 
|  4 | Fin    |    22223 | CA    |
|  5 | Fin    |   444455 | CA    |
+----+--------+----------+-------+
```

1. To find the missing Product # for  Table A, Query is :

```
 SELECT 
       A.`source`,
       A.`id`,
       A. `Product#`
       A.`state`,
  FROM tbl_A AS A
INNER JOIN  Mfg_tbl AS B 
ON A.`id_=B.`id
```

Where  trying to find missing product # from table B( Mfg table). Does Inner join will fill in the blank for missing Product# ? As Inner joins selects records that have matching values in both tables. ID is the common between two.
My this query does not fill in empty Product #. Also will coalesce function work here ? As coalesce will only bring in data for missing Product # only.

expected o/p is :

```
+----+--------+----------+-------+
| ID | Source | Product# | State |
+----+--------+----------+-------+
|  1 | Fin    |    22200 | CA    |
|  2 | Mfg    |   111225 | CA    |
|  3 | Fin    |    44445 | CA    |
|  4 | Fin    |    22223 | CA    |
|  5 | Fin    |   444455 | CA    |
+----+--------+----------+-------+
```

2. How can I compare all the Product # from table B to Table A. 
   Query to check if all my product # from table A is available in Table B?

```
  SELECT 'Product#',
  CASE WHEN A.`Product#` IS NOT NULL THEN 'Match' 
  ELSE'No Match' 
  END AS 'Do they match ?'
  FROM TABLE A
  LEFT JOIN TABLE B  ON A.id=B.id
```

I am able to execute this query, but it returns null.
How can I combine these two query for optimized solution ? Thanks.

expected o/p is :

```
+----+--------+----------+-------+----------------------------+
| ID | Source | Product# | State |      Do they Match ?       |
+----+--------+----------+-------+----------------------------+
|  1 | Fin    |    22200 | CA    | Yes they are in table B    |
|  2 | Mfg    |   111225 | CA    | No they are not in table B |
|  3 | Fin    |    44445 | CA    | Yes they are in table B    |
|  4 | Fin    |    22223 | CA    | Yes they are in table B    |
|  5 | Fin    |   444455 | CA    | Yes they are in table B    |
+----+--------+----------+-------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: I have a strong opinion that making https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, and supplying us with source data and expected output will help this question.

Comment: @ЯрославМашко I just edited code with desired o/p. Please give me the optimized query for both .

Comment: Where is your table B?

Comment: Table B ID | Source | Product# | State |
+----+--------+----------+-------+
|  1 | Fin    |    22200 | CA    |
|  2 | Fin   |   111225 | CA    |
|  3 | Fin    |    44445 | CA    |
|  4 | Fin    |    22223 | CA    |
|  5 | Fin    |   444455 | CA

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @newtechy please move your comment with table B to the answer post. This way it would be easier for the people on SO to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
  SELECT 'Product#',
          CASE WHEN A.`Product#` = B.`Product#` THEN 'Yes they are in table B' 
          ELSE'No they are not in table B' END AS 'Do they match ?'
  FROM TABLE A
  LEFT JOIN TABLE B  ON A.id=B.id
```

Comment: this query does not get me blank Product #. If you see the 1st query, ask is to get the blank Product # from table B and then further comparing Products# exists in two tables.